# Maven release plugin remove old versions

Tags: maven, deployment, github, artifact

We use maven release-plugin and github for deploy artifacts. When we do mvn release:perform this plugin deploy artifact to specified branch in github, but doesn't keep old artifact. As a result we can't build project with old version in dependencies (exclude when this version already in local m2 repository). What can we do with this problem?

Thank in advance!

Comment: You can always checkout some old tag, can't you?

Comment: You must be aware that git is not repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva. So the best solution is to use some of them insteaf of Git (nor any kind of version control).

Comment: Yes, we can checkout, but in project, where we use it we can't build project if in dependency old version

Comment: Now github is package manager :)